# JSF Login with Facebook (SocialAuth) and keeping Session alive

Tags: facebook, jsf, authentication, facebook-login, socialauth

I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while, and I've re-formulated my question a few times. I'll be explicit with this one, providing the implementation below:

---

**index.xhtml**, the short version.

```
...
<f:event listener="#{userBacking.pullUserInfo}" type="preRenderView" />

<h:commandLink action="#{userBacking.login()}"  value="Login"  rendered="#{!userBacking.isLoggedIn()}"/>
<h:commandLink action="#{userBacking.logout()}" value="Logout" rendered="#{userBacking.isLoggedIn()}" />

<h:outputText rendered="#{userBacking.isLoggedIn()}" value="#{userBacking.userProfile.fullName}" />
...
```

---

**UserBacking.java**

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBacking implements Serializable
{

    // ==================== 2. Instance Fields ============================

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2262690225818595135L;

    /**
     * This is static for now. In the future, Google (and others) may be implemented.
     */
    public static final String SOCIAL_PROVIDER_ID = "facebook"; //$NON-NLS-1$


    // ==================== 2. Instance Fields ============================

    private SocialAuthManager socialAuthManager;

    private Profile userProfile;


    // ==================== 6. Action Methods =============================

    public void login() throws Exception
    {
        final Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("graph.facebook.com.consumer_key", FACEBOOK_APP_ID); //$NON-NLS-1$
        props.put("graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret", FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET); //$NON-NLS-1$
        props.put("graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions", "email"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        final SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
        config.load(props);

        socialAuthManager = new SocialAuthManager();
        socialAuthManager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);

        final String authenticationURL = socialAuthManager.getAuthenticationUrl(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_ID, successURL());

        ContextHelper.redirect(authenticationURL);
    }


    public void logout() throws Exception
    {
        socialAuthManager.disconnectProvider(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_ID);

        ContextHelper.invalidateSession();
    }

    /*
     * Should fill up the profile, if a redirect from Facebook appers. Uhhh....
     */
    public void pullUserInfo() throws Exception
    {
        if (userProfile == null && socialAuthManager != null)
        {
            final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ContextHelper.ectx().getRequest();
            final Map<String, String> reqParam = SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap(req);

            final AuthProvider authProvider = socialAuthManager.connect(reqParam);

            userProfile = authProvider.getUserProfile();

            ContextHelper.redirect( ContextHelper.getContextPath() );
        }
    }


    // ==================== 7. Getters & Setters ======================

    public Profile getUserProfile()
    {
        return userProfile;
    }


    public boolean isLoggedIn()
    {
        return userProfile != null;
    }


    // ==================== 9. Convenience Methods ========================

    private static String successURL()
    {
        return IApplicationConstants.APP_PSEUDO_URL + ContextHelper.getContextPath();
    }

}
```

---

**My story**

- Works fine if a Facebook session doesn't exist in the browser. If I'm already logged in, it seems that the `socialAuthManager` is NULL when a `code` in the request params appears.
- I use `index.xhtml` for both login and callback.
- The `f:event` fires `pullUserInfo()` each time the view renders, hoping that when the method fires, a `code` is provided in the request params. I am aware that this is all wrong.
- Can this be done with a filter (i.e. when Facebook calls back with a `code`)?
- I'm not the biggest JSF expert, so I might be missing some basic knowledge.

---

**References**

- [Mr James - Implement Facebook login in JSF using SocialAuth](http://mrj4mes.blogspot.ro/2013/03/how-to-implement-facebook-login-in-jsf.html)
- [How use SocialAuth with JSF to redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125452/how-use-socialauth-with-jsf-to-redirect)
- [This very pretty flowchart](http://socialauth.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/images/socialauth_flow_diagram_2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward, and stupid at the same time.

[Session is lost and created as new in every servlet request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138245/session-is-lost-and-created-as-new-in-every-servlet-request)

I'm firing the login from `http://devel-win8:1381/app/login`, but the callback is found at `http://dev-machine:1381/app/callback` (this is a different implementation, with servlets, but it will work with the code in the question as well).

The browser creates different session for 'naked' host names.

Cheers.